# Uploading Image to Server in Base64 using Alamofire iOS

Tags: python, ios, swift, iphone, base64

I need to send image in base64 on server but i tried every method but no luck still getting error 500 Internal Server Error. 
But when i try to do same thing on POSTMAN it works just fine. I attached screenshot of postman. Please help, i'm stuck on this from few days now.

```
func sendImageToServer(image:UIImage){
        SVProgressHUD.show()
        let imageData = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.2)!.base64EncodedData()
        Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { (multipartFormdata) in
                multipartFormdata.append(imageData, withName: "image", fileName: "photo.png", mimeType: "image/png")

        }, to: "http://35.180.52.242:5000/predict", method: .post, headers: headers()) { (result) in
            switch result {
            case .success(let upload, _, _):

                upload.uploadProgress(closure: { (progress) in
                    print("Upload Progress: \(progress.fractionCompleted)")
                })

                upload.responseJSON { response in
                    print(response)
                    SCLAlertView().showError("Error", subTitle: response.response?.description ?? "")
                    SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
                }

            case .failure(let encodingError):
                print(encodingError)
                SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
            }
        }
    }
    func headers()->HTTPHeaders{
        return ["Content-Type": "application/json"] as HTTPHeaders
    }
```

This what Response look like.

> - some :  { URL: http://35.180.52.242:5000/predict } { Status Code: 500, Headers {
>     "Content-Length" =     (
>         291
>     );
>     "Content-Type" =     (
>         "text/html"
>     );
>     Date =     (
>         "Fri, 22 Feb 2019 22:26:03 GMT"
>     );
>     Server =     (
>         "Werkzeug/0.14.1 Python/2.7.15"
>     );
>     } }

[image]

Comment: That might not be the issue, but: "image/png" + `jpegData()`, clearly that's sounds weird.

Comment: it was jpg before and was not working then did some changes.

Comment: Was it `image/jpeg`?

Comment: yes it was jpeg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try removing the manually set headers `headers: headers()`? Alamofire should be setting those headers for multipart form data and my guess it that you're overriding them with `application/json`

Comment: Remove the fileName parameter in the `multipartFormdata.append(imageData, withName: "image", fileName: "photo.png", mimeType: "image/png")` line and set the correct mimeType and it should work.

Comment: Hi, when sending the following curl command, it works, so it's not an issue with POSTMAN, it has to do with how the call is built:

`curl -X POST \
  http://35.180.52.242:5000/predict \
  -H 'Postman-Token: bab85ca0-039a-472c-a616-f0b1f98f8eca' \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -H 'content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW' \
  -F 'image=iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAYAAAAfFcSJAAAADUlEQVR42mNk+P+/HgAFhAJ/wlseKgAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=='`